# How to loop through arrays in my basic calculator

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, calculator, element

So I have this code and I am puzzled over how I could loop through the size of the array made up of chars by putting the number of elements in the loop conditions without having to manually put in a number like say "i < 4" but rather use the array itselfs and check its size.

I tried using std:array and passing it thru a for-range loop but that didn't give me much success.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int r = 0;
    while (r == 0)
    {
        char op;
        float num1, num2;
        char operators[] = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        bool check1 = false;

        cin >> num1;

        cin >> op;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            if (op == operators[i]) {
                check1 = true;
                break;
            }
        }...
```

sorry for intendation :) still learning how to post code correctly

Comment: What was the problem with the range-based `for` loop?

Comment: What `success` are you referring to? Social status, money, power or something else?

Comment: If you redefine `operators` as `std::vector<char>`, you can then use `operators.size()` to query the length of the vector. Additionally, that lets you write much cleaner range-based for loops: `for (char ch : operators){ if (op == ch){ check1 = true; break; } }`

Comment: @alterigel range-based `for` loops also work with C style arrays (when they don't decay to pointers)

Comment: or you could find the size of array like `*(&operators +1)-operators` ;)

Comment: So I tried:`for(const char &ops : operators) { ...same code as in other foor loop }` and I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: `for(const auto *ops : operators) { ...same code as in other foor loop }`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int r = 0;
    while (r == 0)
    {
        char op;
        float num1, num2;
        char operators[] = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        int size=*(&operators +1)-operators;
        bool check1 = false;

        cin >> num1;

        cin >> op;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            if (op == operators[i]) {
                check1 = true;
                break;
            }
        }...
```

This works for all 1D arrays.
How this works?**Pointers**.

&operators ==> Pointer to an array of 4 elements.

(&operators + 1) ==> Address of 4 chars ahead as
               pointer type is pointer to array
               of 4 chars.

*(&operators + 1) ==> Same address as (&operators + 1), but 
                type of pointer is "char *".

*(&opeartors + 1) - operators ==> Since *(&operators + 1) points 
                   to the address 4 char
                   ahead of operator, the difference
                   between the two is 4.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Could you explain how size works? How does it get the correct number of elements in these arrays?

Comment: Hello if this answer works for you make sure to upvote and accept.I will edit my answer to explain it.

Comment: so since my pointer type is a pointer of array with 4 elements, when I had +1 then it points to the adress 4 chars. And same would apply if it was 5 elements instead of 4 if I understood correctly, meaning 5 elements ahead? And *(&operators + 1) gets the actual value which is 8 if I am right? So size is equal to 4?

Comment: NO.`operators` has the type `char *`, where as `&operators+1` has the type `char (*)[size]`.So to make both operands of the same type(char*) we do `*(&operators+1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int r = 0;
    while (r == 0)
    {
        char op;
        float num1, num2;
        char operators[] = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        bool check1 = false;

        cin >> num1;

        cin >> op;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(operators); i++) 
        {
            if (op == operators[i]) {
                check1 = true;
                break;
            }
        }...
```

it only work for character array and if you want to do for another datatype array just divide sizeof() function with size of datatype

Answer (score 0):

You could use use `std::begin` and `std::end`. The functions are defined in the iterator header.

By using these functions you will be able to obtain iterators to the beginning and end of the array, and you will also be able to more easily substitute the container for your operators for a `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::set`.

```
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    char arr[] = {/*Some content*/};
    for(auto it = std::begin(arr); it != std::end(arr); ++it)
    {
        //Do things here...
    }
}
```

The iterator header also contains some other functions for finding distances between iterators, so if you you really just want the size of the array then `auto size = std::distance(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));` Will find the distance between the beginning and end of the array which is the size.

The application of this in your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int r = 0;
    while(r == 0)
    {
        char op;
        float num1, num2;
        char operators[] = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
        bool check1 = false;

        std::cin >> num1;
        std::cin >> op;
        for(auto it = std::begin(operators); it != std::end(operators); ++it)
        {
            if (op == *it)
            {
                check1 = true;
                break;
             }
        } ...
```

Since this code is now using the iterators, this also means that you may use the range based algorithms which the standard library defines. The algorithm header contains the `std::find` function which could be used as follows in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int r = 0;
    while(r == 0)
    {
        char op;
        float num1, num2;
        char operators[] = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
        bool check1 = false;

        std::cin >> num1;
        std::cin >> op;
        check1 = std::count(std::begin(operators), std::end(operators), op);
        ...
```

I would suggest becoming familiar with iterators in C++ as they are used extensively in the STL. The last line works by counting the elements in the array which are equal to the `op` between the beginning and end of the array, then the number is converted to a bool, so if nothing is found, you will get `false`; however, you could replace the `std::count` with `std::find` but it will require you to check if the search was successful as such `check1 = std::find(std::begin(operators), std::end(operators), op) != std::end(operators);`.

Comment: So I could do for(auto size = std::distance(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)) : operators) {...} ?

Comment: Indeed. Or if you just want to loop through all the elements, then you could dereference the iterator while it is not equal to the end iterator.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to recognise the loop in you comment.

const auto size = std::distance(std::begin(operators), std::end(operators)); will get you the size, so now it will be possible to write the loop

for(auto i = 0; i < size; ++i)

Comment: but I just want one loop that loops thru all elements without me having to manually change the number whenever i add new elements and thus increasing the number of elements in it. How do I define "size" in the for loop? And can I do the for range loop to loop thru the array?

Comment: You don't actually need the size, all you need is the beginning and end of the array which is what the begin and end functions will provide. The you can just loop through the array from the beginning to the end.

Comment: I have updated the answer to demonstrate how iterators may be used.

Comment: but the last line u used with find won't it skip the last slot in the array? cuz if "op" is the last operator in the array then std::end(operators) will be triggered right? or am I wrong? :/

Comment: The end iterator points to a theoretical last element, so in the case of an array or vector, the iterator is the element after the last element in the array; when the iterator is equal to the end iterator, it no longer represents a valid element, furthermore, dereferencing an end iterator is undefined behaviour I believe.

Comment: I see so the "end" is basically after the last element and not the last element itself? :)

Comment: Precisely! You should always check that your iterator is not the end iterator of the container that you are using. I personally like the iterators in C++ because when working with containers such as the vector, it is very easy to sort either the entire vector or only part of the vector using the iterators.